# independent search bar and table view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking, uisearchbar

I am beginner in objective-c and I'm trying to make a client application. There will be a search bar(not text field) and table view in the initial view controller. I completed the table view part, it consists of photo posts. And I want to use the search bar for searching the usernames or tags, I will use the AFNetworking for that. When username was searched, profile picture and username must be displayed in a new table view controller. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

iOS has a built in search bar you can utilize (programmatically or in interface builder) . When return is clicked on the keyboard you can segue to the new view controller and display the results.

This is the method you can implement to detect search is clicked on the keyboard:

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar